# How to submit innerHTML output with other form contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am displaying values with jquery when a user clicks svg/image, sample of my code:

```
function handvalue() {
  document.getElementById("valuenow").innerHTML = "Your hand needs surgery";
```

I am displaying the innerHTML value on a HTML field inside a form plugin, the problem is that whenever the form is submitted, the innerHTML value is not send to the set email together with other form contents, any idea on how to send the HTML contents with other form contents?

Comment: What type of element is `#valuenow`? If it really is a form field you should use `value`, not `innerHTML`. We need to see the relevant HTML to confirm this

Comment: valuenow is the id to display the content to an html field; '<p id="valuenow"></p>'

Comment: Then the problem is because `p` elements are not sent in a form request. You need to use an actual form field control, such as `input`, and set its `value` property

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I need to clarify something, a user only clicks the part they are suffering from then jquery outputs whats needed to be done, the user does not input anything.

Comment: That's aside from the problem. For data to be sent in a form submission it ***has*** to be in form controls. If you don't want the user to see them use `<input type="hidden" />`

Comment: This makes sense now, thanks

Comment: Glad it helped. I added an answer for you below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the code in the question, and your comment under the question:

> `valuenow` is the id to display the content to an html field; `<p id="valuenow"></p>`

The issue is because `p` elements are not included in the data sent in a form submission. You need to place the string in to the `value` of a form control for this to work as you require. Given that you state you don't want the user to type any value, or see one, I'd suggest using a hidden input, something like this:

```
<form action="yourpage/" method="post">
  <!-- other form controls... -->
  <input type="hidden" name="valuenow" id="valuenow" />
</form>
```

```js
function handvalue() {
  document.getElementById("valuenow").value = "Your hand needs surgery";
}
```